# Trigger Push Notification from ASP.Net Api to Xamarin.Android App through FireBase

Tags: asp.net-web-api, push-notification, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

Can I use `GCM Firebase` to send push notification to my `xamarin.android` through my `Asp.net.Web.Api`?

I'm planning to do this: my `web api` will trigger `GCM FireBase` to send push notification to my android app. So when data in my web api (in this condition: datetime) is today date. it will trigger to send push notification to my android app project. But I have no idea to do that. Maybe someone here can help me for procedures or the documentation so I can learn it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use your ASP.Net Web-Api to trigger a fcm push notification(Did it myself recently)

There is a detailed guide on how to use it in this medium blog [here](https://medium.com/kzsoftworks/firebase-push-notifications-using-a-net-backend-dc91fcc39672), it is a well documented blog and has all the required information.

In case of queries feel free to revert